# Sort the integers of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, integer

I'm trying to sort the integers of an array, but I keep getting errors with what I try. I've tried sort(array); array.sort(); Arrays.sort(array); and Arrays.sort(); but nothing works. Help would be appreciated. The error I get for this Arrays.sort(array) is Cannot find symbol, symbol variable Arrays location: class Main

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[20];
    array = fillArray(array);
    printArray(array);
    array = sortArray(array);
    printArray(array);
}

public static int[] fillArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 99);

    }

    return array;
}

public static void printArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.print(" | ");
        }
        System.out.print(array[i]);

    }
}

public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {

    Arrays.sort(array);
    return array;

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you tell us you get errors but don't tell us which ones? We can't help you with _nothing_. You have to tell us _something_.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Your code does work. (It does sort the array.) I believe your confusion might be because the unsorted and sorted output of `printArray` appear together on the same line and it is very hard to see. Put a line break at the end of the `printArray` method, and it will be clear that the result is sorted:

```
System.out.println();
```

The output now is (for example):

```
78 | 42 | 88 | 11 | 40 | 64 | 37 | 78 | 42 | 35 | 77 | 33 | 33 | 5 | 89 | 12 | 32 | 86 | 24 | 79
5 | 11 | 12 | 24 | 32 | 33 | 33 | 35 | 37 | 40 | 42 | 42 | 64 | 77 | 78 | 78 | 79 | 86 | 88 | 89
```

Edit: Based on the error message you've now provided, the problem is that [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is a class in the `java.util` package, and you haven't imported the class or qualified access to it. Put this line at the top of the file:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

*Or*, when you call the method, use what is called its "fully-qualified name":

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(array);
```

See [Using Package Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) in the Java tutorial for the details.

Comment: It doesn't work though, the program errors on the sortArray method.

Comment: @JarodWood What error? Did you make sure to `import java.util.Arrays;` or `import java.util.*;` at the top of the file?

Comment: He never imports java.util.Arrays. That is the exact problem, and one that could have been solved easily if he'd bothered to post the complete code and given an exact description of the problem.

Comment: Ah no import! That fixed it, still learning right now! Thanks for the help man rather then being rude like some.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code you used is working.

You can make some change in main method to make the array printed in console more cleraly.

like

```
    System.out.println("Before sorting...");
    printArray(array);
    array = sortArray(array);
    System.out.println("\nAfter sorting...");
    printArray(array);
```

**An run example is as follows:**

```
Before sorting...
47 | 68 | 94 | 17 | 99 | 60 | 92 | 61 | 44 | 99 | 64 | 37 | 15 | 79 | 38 | 52 | 77 | 41 | 62 | 88
After sorting...
15 | 17 | 37 | 38 | 41 | 44 | 47 | 52 | 60 | 61 | 62 | 64 | 68 | 77 | 79 | 88 | 92 | 94 | 99 | 99
```